# Showing that $\mathcal{H}^{(n)}$ is complete

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

I was wondering about how to prove that

$$ \mathcal{H}^{(n)}:= \mathcal{H} \oplus \mathcal{H} \oplus \dots \oplus \mathcal{H} $$

is still a Hilbert space with norm and inner product
$$\|(x_1,x_2, \dots, x_n)\|^2 = \|x_1\|^2 + \dots+\|x_n\|^2 \hspace{6mm} \langle(x_1,x_2, \dots, x_n),(y_1,y_2, \dots, y_n)\rangle = \sum_{i=1}^n \langle x_i,y_i\rangle_{\mathcal{H}} $$

How to prove that such a space is complete having that $\mathcal{H}$ is Hilbert?

Comment: in my opinion, prove that if $\vec{x}_n$ is a Cauchy sequence in $\mathcal{H}^{(n)}$, then for each $i$, the sequence of $i$-th coordinates of the $\vec{x}_n$ is a Cauchy sequence in $\mathcal{H}$, thus it has a limit...